# How to uninstall a python package that I installed after compiling it with bazel?

Tags: python

I installed tensorflow after compiling it with bazel. Now I want to remove it.

My default python is python3.6, but this installation was done on python3.5.

How do I go about uninstalling tensorflow and removing all traces of the bazel installation?

Comment: IIRC you only compile/build it with bazel, the actual installation is with `pip`.

Comment: i installed this ages ago, so i do not remember what i did actually. if i try to uninstall with pip, it works for python3.6 which is the default python in the system. but this python3.5 installation remains intact.

Comment: If you can't remember, then provide more details about the installation so we can try and figure out what you did to get here. Where is this python3.5 installation located? How did you get a python3.5 environment?

Comment: python3.5 is located in /usr/bin/local along with python3.6. i followed the instructions given here: https://www.pytorials.com/install-tensorflow141-gpu/

Comment: And those instructions use `pip` to install tensorflow, like I said. Double check which `pip` you're using. If you have two installations of Python, maybe you  overwrote the `pip` command from one of them with the other, but you should still be able to do `python3.5 -m pip ...`

Comment: thanks! it works. please add an answer so i can accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bazel is only used for building Tensorflow; the actual installation is done with `pip`. So you need to uninstall it via `pip` as well.

If you installed two versions of Python to `/usr/local`, it's possible that the second installation overwrote the `/usr/local/bin/pip` command from the first. So you no longer have a `pip` command for the first version. However, the command is just a wrapper, and you can use Python directly to run the `pip` module, which functions just like the `pip` command:

```
python3.5 -m pip ...
```

With this you can install/remove packages for that version of Python.

However, for the future, I strongly recommend using virtual environments (via `pipenv` or anaconda, etc.) instead of installing to `/usr/local`, for better isolation. Installing to `/usr/local` also typically requires root, and it's a security risk to run arbitrary scripts downloaded from the internet as root (which is essentially what `pip` does with `setup.py`).